# Bigquery storage grpc write api

Tags: go, google-bigquery, protocol-buffers

My use case here is to read from database and write it into bigquery table.
For this i am trying to use [grpc api](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#using_the_grpc_api_directly)

And Following this [example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigquery/storage/apiv1beta2/big_query_write_client_example_test.go) file. Considiring myself new to protobuf and golang I am unable to figure out how to write a DB row into bigquery table. Specifically confused about this [part](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/33dd86d822fc4d68e11c4dc8f4bbc0d704314774/bigquery/storage/apiv1beta2/big_query_write_client_example_test.go#L69). Not able to find any particular example of creating request in protobuf byte sequence and streaming it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go client provides a [managedWriter](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/tree/main/bigquery/storage/managedwriter) that you can use to stream data more easily. You can see how it is used in the [integration tests](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/main/bigquery/storage/managedwriter/integration_test.go).

Also, if you are new to Go, do you consider using Java instead? There is a JsonStreamWriter available in Java that allows you to append JSONArray objects (as opposed to protobuf rows) and the samples are here: https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquerystorage/tree/main/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/bigquerystorage